# UDP DatagramSocket and Multicast IP

Tags: c#, network-programming, windows-runtime, udpclient, .net-4.5

I'm having a bit of an issue here with receiving messages on client:

Essentially, I'am able to send a message "Hello world" to the listener, but when the listener tries to send "Reply", the client does not get the message?

What do you think I am missing here?

Client:

```
        var socket = new DatagramSocket();
        socket.MessageReceived += HandleMessageReceive;
        await socket.ConnectAsync(new Windows.Networking.HostName("224.192.12.12"), "9991");
        socket.JoinMulticastGroup(_multicastGroupIp);

        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(_socket.OutputStream);
        writer.WriteString("Hello world");
        await writer.StoreAsync();
```

Listener:

```
            var stateObject = new StateObject();
            stateObject.LocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9991);
            stateObject.SocketClient = new UdpClient();

            stateObject.SocketClient.Client.Bind(stateObject.LocalEndPoint);
            stateObject.SocketClient.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse("224.192.12.12"));
            stateObject.SocketClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(HandleDiscoveryServiceReceive), stateObject);

private static void HandleDiscoveryServiceReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            var stateObject = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;

            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = stateObject.LocalEndPoint;

            byte[] data = stateObject.SocketClient.EndReceive(ar, ref localEndPoint);
            string decodedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Got something back: {0}", decodedData);

            UdpClient client = stateObject.SocketClient;
            client.MulticastLoopback = false;
            byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("REPLY");
            IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("224.192.12.12"), 9991);
            client.Send(msg, msg.Length, remoteEndPoint);

            client.BeginReceive(HandleDiscoveryServiceReceive, stateObject);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be sending the reply to the wrong address:port. You've hard wired it: why? The remote address:port are made available by the receive. Use that.